# Implementing UUID as primary key in Laravel intermediate table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, uuid

I'm interested in using UUIDs as primary keys in an intermediate table. I'm aware that adding `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids;` and `use HasUuids;` to a model can achieve this. However, since I don't have or need a model for my intermediate table, I'm uncertain if it's possible to automatically create UUIDs similarly. Will I need to manually generate the UUID when I create an entry in my intermediate table?

Here's what my migration file looks like:

```php
public function up(): void {
    Schema::create('post_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('body');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel, UUIDs can be automatically generated for models using the `HasUuids` trait. However, for intermediate tables without a model, you would need to manually generate the UUID when creating an entry. One way to do this is using Laravel's built-in `Str::uuid()` method when inserting data into the table.

```php
DB::table('post_user')->insert([
    'id' => (string) Str::uuid(),
    'title' => $title,
    'body' => $body,
    'created_at' => now(),
    'updated_at' => now(),
]);
```